# Racing wheel controllers for XBox 360

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I'd like to pick up a racing wheel for the Xbox 360 (bonus points if it supports PC and/or PS3 as well), but I can't find any that seem to be still distributed. Logitech's and Mad Catz's models are discontinued and I can't find even the original Microsoft one either.

Are there particular flaws with the controllers that their respective manufacturers stopped making them? Am I just going to open myself to a world of frustration if I pick one up from eBay or Craigslist?

And while I'm on the subject, are there any wheels still in production today that I missed? I'm in Canada, but not opposed to buying controllers from other parts of the world so long as they're compatible with North American consoles.

Comment: I'm not sure how this meets the criteria for a shopping recommendation; this is the epitome of what we want and expertise we can bring.  It doesn't want us to recommend a product, but specifically detail aspects everyone can look for when making their own choices.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but for everybody looking for an answer right now this would be my answer:

If you are a bit handy whith electronics you likely find **GIMX** (http://blog.gimx.fr/) useful.

From their website:

> GIMX stands for Game Input MultipleXer or Game Input MatriX. The purpose of this free software is to control a video game console with a computer (e.g. a PC or a Raspberry Pi). It works with the PS3, the Xbox 360, the PS4 and the Xbox One.
>   It operates:
>
> - over bluetooth: works with GNU/Linux (PS3, PS4) only. A compatible
>     bluetooth dongle is required.
> - over usb: works with GNU/Linux and Windows (PS3, PS4, 360, XOne). A USB adapter is required.
>
> The application gets data from the peripherals (mice, keyboards and joysticks) and sends controls to the game console over bluetooth or usb. Other controls such as gesture or voice are possible through the use of external software that emulate peripherals.

Whith GIMX you are able to emulate game controllers. Just find a (second hand) wheel of your taste. Though Logitech Wheels are best supported including some with force feedback (http://blog.gimx.fr/gimx-force-feedback-wheel-support-in-action/)

I just managed to make my 14 year old Microsoft Sidewinder Wheel working with my sons PS4! Though the force feedback is not working (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about racing take a look at [Fanatec](http://www.fanatec.de/) wheels. They are more on expensive side but praised by many for their build quality and force feedback (look for reviews on youtube). They also work on all platforms (except some models).

Answer (score -2):

You can try to look for Thrustmaster's lineup of products. Some of the basic level without FFB are below 100 euros, while the entry level FFB wheels are below 200 euros.